Is it possible for a law to force someone to do something, instead of just imposing criminal penalties for not doing it?
Say there is an obligation imposed by law.
A law could be written that says that people who fail to act as obligated are guilty of a crime of such and such level and shall be punished with such and such a criminal penalty. I might describe this law as "forcing" people to do the thing, but technically that's not true: a person can still simply not do the thing, they just might be caught and criminally punished.
Is there some other way of constructing a law that could genuinely force a person to act as obligated? In jurisdictions with laws of this form, how are they physically enforced?

The legal system can, and does, force people to pay a sum of money by simply taking it away from them.  And so on.

I'm assuming the OP is asking whether someone can be compelled by force to do something, which is not  the same as being punished for not doing it. For example, one cannot be compelled to kill themselves, but they may be executed as a punishment for a crime. Similarly, one cannot be compelled to take money out of their wallet and pay the child support, but they can be arrested and held in custody until they agree to do so, or their property can be taken from them by force through garnishing or foreclosures (but they're not giving it, it is being taken from them).

Are there crimes / offenses anywhere that are punished by a fixed fine only, so someone with enough money can just do this offense again and again?

How do you imagine a person could actually be forced to do anything at all? We're getting into philosophy now, but when it comes down to it, any action you take is a result of your choice to perform that action. If you decide not to perform the action the courts order you to perform, then you've weighed the options and decided to either do or not do the thing. Unless you're considering something like drugging the person so make them compliant, and then ordering them to do such-and-such ...

germany
If you are the driver of a car (this is the most obvious example, I am sure there are others) and you are involved in a serious accident, the police can (sometimes must) order a blood test for alcohol and drugs.
This is not a punishment for a crime. It wasn't established yet, whether a crime even took place.
While this a a whole procedure, it has to be approved by a judge and done by a doctor in a hospital, not just a police officer at night in the dark at the shoulder of a road, you can absolutely be forced to do it.
You cannot politely disagree, and if you get violent, this will just be another stack of charges (resisting law enforcement) on top. But you will be forced, struggle all you want.

In jurisdictions with laws of this form, how are they physically enforced?

The police will restrain you and transport you to the hospital by all means neccessary.

I would assume similar laws and procedures exist in other places all over the world, a blood test is important and time sensitive, you cannot just take it next week and pay a fine for being late. You can also not simply "confess" to the alcohol level you would like to have.

Afaik you can refuse the test. In the US that could lead to a DUI conviction, but no one can forceably take your blood. I'd imagine it would be similar in Germany. Especially Germany, I'd hope...

No, you cannot refuse. Refusing would need some kind of penalty, and since being drunk could, depending on what crime it is, lead to a harsher or lighter sentence, there really is no way to say "oh, don't find out the truth, I want to confess to my truth", nor is there an alcohol level that is "worst" and could be considered a fact instead. And any good lawyer would argue that when you refused that test, you were exactly as drunk as they need you to be for their defense and the refusal was just because you were exactly that drunk... so no... you can and will be forced.

Please note that I am not talking about parking damage because you had a beer. I am talking about running over people. Serious stuff.

In California refusal leads to establishing a fact of DUI. Levels are no longer important or relevant. But I can't imagine anyone being forced to the ground and poked with siringes. Do you have any references?

Okay, even a DUI is different sentences depending on your level of alcohol. And any good lawyer will get you out of a confession you made when you were drunk. So refusing a blood test when you are drunk is really not anything legally admissible in either direction. And again, if you run over your ex-wife in an angry fit of rage, being drunk might even be a factor in lessening your sentence, compared to planning it in advance and doing it in cold blood.

So there is no "You can refuse the test and we will assume the worst for you", because there is no "worst" until you know what crime is charged and what the defence argues. But I have attached the underlying law.

And yes, "without consent" means law enforcement will restrain the person and do it, whether they like it or not.

In Switzerland the law also allows blood test against the will of the person concerned. However, medical professionals are ethically obliged to refuse the procedure without the consent of the patient. No one has actually tested how far the authorities can go to carry out the blood test order...

In UK you can refuse a blood test, in which case you must provide a urine sample.

side note: police will call the emergency judge, and have a warrant filled out with your name on it by the time you are at the hospital, making the blood test court mandated, your own will suddenly superfluous.


Is there some other way of constructing a law that could genuinely
force a person to act as obligated? In jurisdictions with laws of this
form, how are they physically enforced?

Yes, although perhaps not in the ways contemplated by the question.
Orders enforceable only through incarceration, fines, or having someone else act on your behalf
As noted in an answer by Jen, there are mandatory injunctions, but the consequence of violating a mandatory injunction is a fine or incarceration.
A related remedy is to have the court appoint someone else to do a job, such as mowing your own lawn or signing a document that is binding upon you, that ordinarily only you would be allowed to do.
Similarly, courts do routinely impose sentences of community service for minor offenses, but in these cases, if someone fails to carry out their sentence, the consequence is incarceration and not forcing someone to actually conduct the community service.
But these remedies are different than actually being forced to do something, even though they are often sufficient to make someone do something affirmatively and personally.
Modern examples
There are a few other modern examples.
Conscription and military and paramilitary service.
Military conscription is probably the best true example. You can be conscripted into military service and forced to actually show up and serve in a much more intrusive and direct way than merely punishing someone criminally or quasi-criminally for not fulfilling a legal duty.
More generally, anyone who is a member of any military force, even someone who volunteered, and members of certain reserve and paramilitary forces (e.g., reserve soldiers responding to a natural disaster in progress, or Center for Disease Control field agents who go into contagious disease outbreak areas), can be forced to do their jobs.
Forcing someone to leave a place

Someone who is evicted or trespassing or violating a protection order or restraining order can be forced to leave the premises from which they were evicted, were trespassing at, or were ordered by a protection order or restraining order not to be.

People are routinely forced to leave a country or place against their will. This is called deportation.

Some places have a punishment called "exile" which forces people to leave a certain area permanently or for an extended period of time. This is done in the U.S. by a handful of states (mostly in the South) and by some Indian tribes as a tribal justice punishment.


Incident to incarceration and the justice system

People are routinely compelled to provide blood samples and DNA samples and physical examinations (e.g. cavity searches) against their will for testing to provide evidence in lawsuits or criminal cases.

Someone who is incarcerated can be forced to strip for searches and showers. and to go to particular places within the jail or prison at particular times.

It is not unprecedented for a court to order that a person on a hunger strike, generally someone who is incarcerated, be fed against their will.

In some circumstances, criminal defendants who are not competent to stand trial but can be made to be competent by administering psychiatric medicine to them, can be forced to take the psychiatric medicine.

Someone can be forced to take a sobriety test or breath test or searched personally incident to a check point stop, at areas like airport secured areas, or incident to an arrest or police stop short of an arrest.


Incident to health care

Someone in an ordinary hospital can be forcible kept from leaving until discharged by medical personnel, for their own good.

Someone with certain infectious medical conditions (like TB) can be forced to be isolated and to affirmatively forced to take medicine to treat it in the view of health officials.


Incident to incapacity

Someone who lacks mental capacity or is a minor, and has had a guardianship imposed upon them (or implied by law) can be forced by their guardian to receive medical treatments, to locate to a new place (e.g. a long term care facility), to dress and wash themselves, to attend a particular school or church, and so on.

Schools, babysitters, and parents similarly have an invasive ability to force children in their care to do things.

Someone can be involuntarily committed to a mental hospital and can be forced by the mental hospital to be minimally compliant with the mental hospital's directions.


Reproduction related cases

In places where abortion is banned, women can be forced to carry pregnancies to term and give birth.

In some cases, pregnant woman can be detained and supervised to prevent them from using drugs or otherwise harming themselves or obtaining an illegal abortion.

In some jurisdictions, where there is a marital immunity for rape, a husband can force his wife to have sex, although the legal system simply recognizes his right to do so and does not actually enforce it.


Slavery, indentured servitude, serfdom, and wives
Historically (through sometime in the 19th century in most places, but into the 20th century in others) indentured servants and slaves and serfs could be forced to do actual work by their masters, and the state would either not intervene in someone being forced to do so, or would support the master by helping to recapture escaped indentured servants and slaves and serfs, or assisting in disciplining them.
In the even more distant past, such as late medieval and early modern England and Wales, wives were in a similar position with their husbands as their masters and could be forced, with government support, to obey their husbands more generally.
Basically, almost no country, de jure, permits slavery, involuntary servitude, serfdom, or allowing husbands to force their wives to serve them. Some countries where the Islamic State has de facto control would be an exception in recent history and perhaps even today.
U.S. state and federal constitutional law, in theory, still allows someone to be enslaved or subjected to involuntary servitude for a period of time as a punishment for a federal crime, or aas punishment for a state crime in some states (some state constitutions don't allow this to be done, although it was a fairly common punishment in slave staes in the U.S. in the aftermath of the U.S. Civil War).
But no U.S. state authorizes such a punishment. "Chain gangs" where prisoners work for minimal pay or shorter sentences or conditions of incarceration, are, in theory at least voluntary and can be refused. There is also no punishment of this kind authorized by statute for any federal crime committed by a civilian. But hard labor is a common punishment in the Uniform Code of Military Justice in accord with the idea that people who are in military or quasi-military service can be forced to do things.

The closest are the equitable remedies of mandatory injunction or specific performance. These are phrased as orders by the court to do some act.
You could also view a criminal sentence itself as being forced to be imprisoned.
The question of what it means to be obligated, what actually causes that obligation, and the relationship between obligation and the different meanings of "force" is a question at the core of jurisprudence, which explains the disparate views and intuitions on this topic. Some see force in statute, others see force in court orders, others see force in the threat of the state, others only see force in the physical control of a body. These are all views that have been taken in field of jurisprudence.

The law doesn't force anyone to do anything. All it does is to deem some actions to be lawful and others unlawful. It would normally be unlawful for the governor of Pentonville Prison to lock me up in a cell and stop me from leaving. I could challenge that action by such means as applying for a "writ of habeas corpus". Had I been duly imprisoned after conviction for an offence, the governor would respond to the writ by demonstrating that the law gave him authority to maintain my imprisonment. If that authority lapsed due to the passage of time or a successful appeal, or if I'd never been sentenced at all, then the court would say that my continued imprisonment was unlawful.
The direct physical consequences of this legal process are simply that certain pieces of paper get shuffled around. If I am successful before a court then I might get a piece of paper labelled "Order", signed and stamped. The court order has no inherent effect on the world, but it is to be hoped that relevant people would do what it says. If they do not, then there may be escalating sanctions. But again, if someone is fined £500 for contempt of court, and they don't pay, then the legal result is that when a bailiff eventually forces open the person's door to take their TV away and sell it, that bailiff is acting lawfully (whereas a bailiff taking property without legal authority would be committing an offence).
Now, while the threat of state force is always lurking, there are several avenues by which people's conduct can be regulated, short of imposing a criminal penalty immediately. Let's consider the example of me keeping a tiger in my home (in the UK), which is an activity that the state would like to discourage unless I am extremely responsible.

Under the Dangerous Wild Animals Act 1976, it's a criminal offence for me to keep a tiger without the appropriate licence (ss. 1(1) and 2(5)); I can be fined (s. 6(1)). If I don't pay the fine then there are various standard consequences as indicated above.
My local council can take my tiger away without compensating me, and indeed I have to pay the costs of them doing so (s. 4). So an action that ordinarily would be unlawful (it would be theft) is now lawful. The law is authorizing the action on the grounds of public safety rather than to punish me as such, but there's surely still a deterrent effect - perhaps a stronger one than the fine, if I am rich. I do not need to have been convicted before this is triggered.
I can lose any animal-related licences I do have (s. 6(2)). It will obviously be harder to get a tiger licence in the future.
By virtue of the criminal conviction, I might face other administrative sanctions, such as losing the ability to sell alcohol in my restaurant. Generally, if I'm incarcerated then I can lose access to state benefits for the duration; for a long period of imprisonment I might lose my council house.
If my tiger hurts anyone (whether I have a licence or not) then I am liable for its actions. Because a tiger is inherently dangerous, this is the case whether or not I was negligent in how I took care of it (Animals Act 1971 s.2(1); Animals (Scotland) Act 1987 s.1(1)). They can take me to court and I may have to compensate them for their injuries. If I don't pay then we are back to state violence, because I disobeyed the court, but the principal event here is a dispute between citizens.

In sum, even though several of these possibilities can escalate to agents of the state using violence against me or my property, that's not the only tool the law has to shape behaviour. Several of the consquences here do not involve violence at all, but merely the withdrawal of privileges I'd otherwise enjoy.
Finally, there are also situations where my non-compliance can be worked around in law. For example, if I'm a charity trustee neglecting my duties then I can be replaced. If the important thing is that the action be taken, rather than that I personally am the one doing it, then threatening me with criminal consequences isn't necessarily the most effective way to proceed.

If you are willing to accept the punishment: no
If you don’t do something the law requires there is usually a punitive action the government can take. This might be a fine (with the ability to forcefully take your stuff if you don’t pay), or imprisonment. Or death, for countries and crimes with the death penalty. If you accept that, then all laws are optional.
If you repeat the crime, the punishment usually gets steeper each time. Except death - you only get that once.

"You only get [death] once" - not if you annoy the Pope.
